# send email localhost

Tags: ruby-on-rails, email, localhost

I'm developing rails on localhost and wondering what is the simplest way, in terms of workflow, of building email functionality in.

So I figure:

1. Get mail working on localhost.
2. Then when I deploy on a production server just change the smtp settings.

Is this a reasonable approach? Can you actually send email from localhost? Know of any tutorials on email in rails?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

E-mail/SMTP should work fine from any host connected to the internet with access to a DNS server.

I don't see anything wrong with your approach.

Answer (score 0):

agree. Using SMTP is a quick and easy way to get mail up and running on your localhost dev box.